# FeedOptions.PopulateQueryMetrics in Cosmos SDK 3.0

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

There is a property in FeedOptions class named [PopulateQueryMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.populatequerymetrics?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_PopulateQueryMetrics) in Document DB SDK 2.#. What is the equivalent in Cosmos SDK 3.#?

```
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> documentQuery = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(
collectionUri,
sqlQuery,
new FeedOptions
{
EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
PopulateQueryMetrics = true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set this flag anymore, query metrics (plus other important network information and latency metrics) are captured in the `FeedResponse.Diagnostics`. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.response-1.diagnostics?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Response_1_Diagnostics

Just capture this property's value `ToString()`, for example:

```
FeedResponse<T> response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
Console.WriteLine(response.Diagnostics.ToString());
```